# UI5 bind new data to model from controller

Tags: javascript, json, xml, odata, sapui5

I am trying to replace data in my model with an array that that i have manually done work on to filter myself. I get this data from model.read(). The problem is none of the documented ways of updating data in a model in ui5 are working or even seem to respond to being called. I am using odata v2 but all these techniques are documented to work for the v2 model: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/topics/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html

```
filterFeed: function() {
    var model = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
    var view = this.getView();

    model.read("/assessmentFeed", {
        success: function(odata) {
            var comments = odata.results;
            var results = [];

            // ...  do work to fill 'results'

            model.setProperty('/assessmentFeed', results);

            var json = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(results);
            view.setModel(json, "/assessmentFeed");

            var list = view.byId("feedList");
            list.bindAggregation("items", "/assessmentFeed", new sap.m.FeedListItem());
        }
    });
},
```

This is the feed list in my xml view

```
<layout:content>
    <m:FeedInput post="onFeedPost" class="sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom"/>
    <m:List id="feedList" showSeparators="Inner" items="{path: '/assessmentFeed', sorter: {path: 'DATE', descending: true}}">
        <m:FeedListItem sender="{MEMBERID}" timestamp="{DATE}" text="{COMMENT}" convertLinksToAnchorTags="All"/>
    </m:List>
</layout:content>
```

I don't get any errors but no discernible effect after calling all the above functions.

[image]

This is from the model's aBindings array showing that assessmentFeed is in the model's bindings from the chrome debugger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you're trying to put your data in a JSON model and in the oData model?

Controller:

```
        filterFeed: function() {
            var model = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
            var view = this.getView();
            var json = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(); //New JSON model

            model.read("/assessmentFeed", {
                success: function(odata) {
                    var comments = odata.results;
                    var results = [];

                    // ...  do work to fill 'results'

                    view.setModel(json, "JSON"); //Set json model and name it JSON                      
                    json.setProperty("/assessmentFeed", results); //Push results into your json model with path /assessmentFeed             
                }
            });
```

View: Binding Path is `JSON>/assessmentFeed`

```
<layout:content>
    <m:FeedInput post="onFeedPost" class="sapUiSmallMarginTopBottom"/>
    <m:List id="feedList" showSeparators="Inner" items="{path: 'JSON>/assessmentFeed', sorter: {path: 'DATE', descending: true}}">
        <m:FeedListItem sender="{JSON>MEMBERID}" timestamp="{JSON>DATE}" text="{JSON>COMMENT}" convertLinksToAnchorTags="All"/>
    </m:List>
</layout:content>
```

Comment: Changing the path to this seems like it would break the initial call to my service. How would I bridge that gap? I could do this exact thing in the controller init function but is there not a better way that doesn't break the communication with the backend service?

Comment: I've forgotten the model name in  the attributes like "JSON>DATE"

Comment: I don't understand this line of your code: ’view.setModel(json, "/assessmentFeed");’ setModel binds a model to a view and name it. But what ist "/assessmentFeed" in setModel? After reading, your model has automatically the entity assessmentFeed.